# Copy/move constructor elision

Tags: c++

Not sure whether Section 12.8 #31.3

> [...] copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which
> may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference
> ([class.temporary]) would be copied/moved to a class object with the
> same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
> constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the
> omitted copy/move [...]

applies to following:

```
class A {
   public:
     A() {}
     A(const A&) = delete;
     A(A&&) { printf("move"); }
};

void foo(A a) {}

int main() {
  A a;
  foo(std::move(a));
}
```

Is elision allowed in this case? I want to ensure `a` is moved from.

Comment: Not everybody has access to the particular C++ standard you're looking at (released versions are not free and the draft changes all the time). You might want to quote what `Section 12.8 #31.3` says.

Comment: Besides `a` won't be legally acessible after calling `foo(std::move(a));`, what exactly do you want to achieve with that construct? Avoid copying? A `const A &` parameter would already do this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought it would be legally accessible, since the object should be in a valid but unspecified state. I want to pilfer a pimpl.

Comment: Please show an actual [mre], instead of code that fails: 1) due to a typo, a missing close parenthesis, and 2) without a default constructor, `A a` will fail to compile anyway. After fixing those defects the answer to your question would be "yes", however because the shown code is not representative of your real code, any given answer here won't be of much use, since your real code might actually have a different answer.

Comment: @Latsch _"I thought it would be legally accessible"_ No, accessing an instance after it was successfully moved is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: "Unspecified behavior" actually. The moved-from object is in a "valid but unspecified" state.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think it's unspecified. For instance, it's okay to access a moved from `int`.

Comment: _Unspecified_, correct.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I can't post my real code, it's top secret ;) 
So what would prevent elision and how can I enforce moving?

Comment: Well, in that case, it will always write move since you move a named object. **On the other hand, you should never write code that depend on being moved or not**.   In practice, temporary object could be constructed in place instead of being moved.

Comment: You should show a more realistic code of what you want to prevent. It is always possible to imagine code and use case that won't expose your secret.

Comment: Nobody says you have to show your entire code, only a [mre]. Some time ago I found a big in the xfce window manager. My application, that triggered the bug, was about 60k lines long. I wrote a 30 line [mre] that reproduced the bug, posted it to freedesktop's bugzilla, they reproduced it and fixed the bug.